# Tap on TableViewRowAction just disappears action buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a UITableView which in every call has two action.
When I tap on one of them their action not being called and just these action button disappears and cell comes back to its normal place.
their action just being called when I tap and hold for a long time!
how can I fix that?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

   let cancel = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "cacel") { action, index in
      print("c tapped")
    }

   let paymentType = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "patmentType") { action, index in
      print("p tapped")
   }
   return [paymentType,cancel] 
}
```

tableView deleagte is set. 
I tried code below still bot working :

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

and

```
tableView.isEditing = false
```

not working yet.
any help please

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you share demo project?

Comment: @RichieRich how ?

Comment: Just zip it and upload it here: http://www.tinyupload.com

Comment: Can you add `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}` this code

Comment: @RichieRich project is private :(

Comment: @mukesh_lokare i added that berfore .still not working

Comment: Just implement same thing is new project and if you can replicate same thing in another project you can share that.

Comment: @RichieRich i made a test project it worked there!!!

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08543029016200711703   this is my class file

Comment: Sorry can't help you until I got non working project from you.. :)

Comment: it was my non working class @RichieRich 
 
s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08543029016200711703